# how to interpret estimates from Beta GLMM with dummy explanatory variables

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, glmm, beta-regression

I have results of an experiment where each person had to estimate a share of certain types of city dwellers in two cities (A and V), and participants were assigned into one of two treatments (FIN or FIC).

I estimate  a GLMM model following a beta-distribution (with a logit link) with the glmmTMB-package with random-effect for each participant. `target` is a city the share of renters (from 0 to 1) they have to estimate;

```
h1_model_base <- glmmTMB(value ~ target * treatment + (1 | participant),
                         data = temp, family = beta_family())
```

The results (already exponenciated) look like that:

[image]

However, since both `target` and `treatment`  are dummy variables, I can't figure out how the coefficients (such as 0.737 at a treatment==FIC) can be interpreted.

Answer (score 1):

You have two dummy variables, and your model is fit in the logit space. The intercept is the value of your outcome (logit-transformed) when both independent dummy variables are at the reference value. The `targetVoronezh` estimate of 0.974 is the change in the outcome compared to the intercept when `target` is `Voronezh` as compared to the reference category that was absorbed by the Intercept. Importantly, this is the estimate for the difference only for when the `subtreatment` is at its reference level.

The exact same thing for `subtreatmentFIC`. This is the change in the outcome in the logit space when `subtreatment` equals `FIC` as compared to the reference category for `subtreatment` for when `target` is at its reference level only (i.e., not `Voronezh`).

The interaction then represents how the effects of the two variables change when the other variable is not at the reference level. To get the estimate of the outcome for each combination, you have to add the estimates together.

When both dummy variables are at reference level, the estimate for value = 2.96.

When `subtreatment` is at the reference level, but `target` is `Voronezh`, the estimate for `value` can be calculated by adding the Intercept to the effect `targetVoronezh`, like so:

```
2.96+0.974
[1] 3.934
```

When `target` is at the reference level, but `subtreatment` equals `FIC`, you get the estimate of the outcome `value` by adding together the Intercept and the effect `subtreatmentFIC`, like this:

```
> 2.96+0.737
[1] 3.697
```

Now, the interaction is a little bit trickier. To get the effect you have to add up the relevant effects, as the interaction is reporting the difference in the effect. So, for example, to get the difference between the reference level of `target` and when `Voronezh` *when subtreatment equals FIC*, you need to add the Intercept, the effect for `targetVoronezh`, and the interaction, like this:

```
2.96+0.974+1.336
[1] 5.27
```